# Problems with AWS roles - running containers in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I created a number of roles to give me access to S3 and other services through AWS SageMaker and it works fine when I run codes on notebooks.

Then, I turn the code into a .py file to run it in a container. My final goal is to run the image on AWS Batch, so I created the roles regarding the EC2 and Batch. But before sending the image to ECR, I test it on SageMaker by running the container.

What happens is that the container runs fine on Batch but the same doesn't happen on SageMaker, I have two issues:

1) When I try to read a file on S3, it runs fine on a SageMaker notebook or on Batch, but when I run the container on SageMaker, the access to S3 is denied.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

2) When I use an AssumeRole, it runs fine on a SageMaker notebook and on Batch either, but when I run the container on SageMaker, the following error occurs:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::someUser:assumed-role/BaseNotebookInstanceEc2InstanceRole/codeRole is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::myAccount:role/myRole
```

Note that "someUser" is a ficticious user created randomly with a number of account that is not mine and I don't know from where this number came from.
I want to make it work using roles and I must not use access keys by any means.
If it helps, my Dockerfile has the following steps:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install numpy==1.17.3
RUN pip install pandas==0.24.1
RUN pip install boto3==1.11.5
RUN pip install s3fs==0.4.0

RUN mkdir /src
COPY . /src

CMD ["python", "/src/my File.py"]
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problems? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you are executing the batch inference on a notebook instance or on the Batch platform, you've already logged in to your AWS account so the Python script can run successfully.

However, when you are executing the code (fetching resources from S3 bucket, etc), the user might not have access to your AWS account tokens (depend on your aws configuration).

Were you be able to get_caller_identity when you ran the Python code in the container? For more information about roles and permissions, please see the documentation here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html

Also please check your S3 bucket policy to make sure your object is accessible by SageMaker and your account.